# SSMS Edit xxx Rows feature no longer works SQL Server Management Studio version 18.12.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

After updating SSMS to 18.12.1, the latest version as of June 2023, I noticed that I can no longer use the Edit Top 200 Rows feature any more.
When right-clicking on the table, and selecting "Edit Top 200 Rows", a new tab opens, but nothing is shown inside of it (completely blank, no table).
I understand this is "bad practice", however, when developing and tweaking, directly editing a table is a feature that has been with SSMS for over 20 years (and I've been using it for quick changes while debugging).
I believe this is a bug, but want to make sure (since I was using it fine just a few months ago).
Any ideas?

NOTE: It does not work for local nor remote databases, nor when started as admin or not. Just a blank tab window (no errors in any logs that I can find). Weird.

Comment: I have 18.12.1 installed, I can confirm the feature works when I test it and appears unchanged to how it worked in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll uninstall and reinstall it again. Must have become corrupted

Comment: Is not the version 19.1 uptodate?

Comment: I just now saw that. SSMS said it was updated, but apparently, it no longer prompts to update to latest release (major version) like it used to.

Comment: Honestly, just don't use the feature anyway. It's feature lackimg, quirky and buggy. Learn how to use appropriate DML statements, your life will be much better for it.

Comment: The reason you got a blank screen is likely because you are using SQL Server 2022, which SSMS 18 does not support.

Comment: Thanks Thom A.  I just installed ver SSMS 19 and it's working fine now.  Regarding writing queries, that is not a problem, just slows me down when plopping in multiple test values repeatedly and I get paid via the project, not hourly, so it's just about time saving convenience.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use the designer/table editor. It's broken in so many ways. Either use T-SQL only, or use a better tool such as DataGrip